# How can I use an extension to add interface conformance to a type that is outside my control?

Tags: extension-methods, beef

On the [**extensions** page](https://www.beeflang.org/docs/language-guide/datatypes/extensions/) of the Beef documentation, it says this:

> Extensions can be useful for adding interface conformance to types that are outside your control (ie: system types or types defined in another library).

Unfortunately, it doesn't provide an example of that use case, and I don't know how to proceed.

Suppose I have an interface `IFooBarable`:

```
interface IFooBarable
{
    void FooBar();
}
```

And I would like to add this extension method to the system library type `System.DateTime`:

```
namespace System
{
    extension DateTime
    {
        public void FooBar()
        {
            String s = scope .();
            ToLongTimeString(s);

            Console.WriteLine("This dateTime ({}) has FooBarred", s); 
        }
    }
}
```

... such that DateTime can implement `IFooBarable`.

Is there supposed to be a way one can tell the compiler to treat `DateTime` as an implementation of `IFooBarable`? For instance, such that this compiles:

```
using System;

interface IFooBarable
{
    void FooBar();
}

/* extension code here */

namespace Program
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IFooBarable t = DateTime.Now;

            t.FooBar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's as easy as using the same syntax as what indicates implementation in a class declaration. That is to say, all you need to do above is use `extension DateTime : IFooBarable`:

```
using System;

interface IFooBarable
{
    void FooBar();
}

namespace System
{
    extension DateTime : IFooBarable
    {
        public void FooBar()
        {
            String s = scope .();
            ToLongTimeString(s);

            Console.WriteLine("This dateTime ({}) has FooBarred", s); 
        }
    }
}

namespace Program
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IFooBarable t = DateTime.Now;

            t.FooBar();
        }
    }
}
```

You can even do this to register a method that a class already has as an implementation of an interface's method of the same name by not having anything inside the `extension`:

```
using System;

interface IFooBarable
{
    void ToLongTimeString();
}

namespace System
{
    extension DateTime : IFooBarable
    {
    }
}

namespace Program
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IFooBarable t = DateTime.Now;

            String s = scope .(); 
            t.ToLongTimeString(s);

            Console.WriteLine("{}", s);
        }
    }
}
```